# unzip the file in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

My script :
    #!/usr/local/bin/perl

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($artifact, $package_id) = @ARGV;
print $artifact;
print $package_id;


if($artifact =~ /\.zip$/i)
    {
    chdir("/apps/checkout/artifactory/xxkintana/$package_id");
    unzip  $artifact;

 }
```

Run :  ./script.pl test-1.0.zip 4370177

Error :

Can't locate object method "unzip" via package "test-1.0.zip" (perhaps you forgot to load "test-1.0.zip"?) at ./script.pl line 16.

Please help me

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the module [`Archive::Zip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive%3a%3aZip) to pull files from a zip archive.

The module contains an [`examples directory`](https://metacpan.org/source/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.37/examples) including one named [`extract.pl`](https://metacpan.org/source/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.37/examples/extract.pl)

Comment: Thanks Miller.. i got from examples which you have given.my $zip =      Archive::Zip->new();
my $status = $zip->read( $artifact );
$zip->extractTree();